# equation of the tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an equation of the tangent plane to the surface at the given point. $g(x, y) = x^2-y^2$ at $(7, 2, 45)$. I know the answer is between $14(x-7)-4(y-2)+(z-45)=0$ or $14(x-7)-4(y-2)-(z-45)=0$. I think it is $14(x-7)-4(y-2)+(z-45)=0$. Am I right? If not, please explain why I am not.

Comment: You are incorrect, actually. Write $g$ in a different way: $h(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 - z = 0$. This defines a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and so the tangent plane and gradient of $h$ are perpendicular. What is the gradient of $h$?

Comment: @Cameron Williams what do you mean?

Comment: @jainsmit, see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GradientVectorTangentPlane.aspx).

Comment: @CameronWilliams so it would be 14(x−7)−4(y−2)+(z−45)=0

Comment: @jainsmit written in the form $z = g(x,y) = x^2-y^2$ doesn't quite work with the prescription given in the notes I sent so it's better to write it as a function of three variables (my $h$ above). Do you see that $h(x,y,z) = x^2-y^2-z = 0$ is equivalent to $z = g(x,y) = x^2-y^2$? With that said, if you find the gradient of $h$ and apply their prescription to find the tangent plane to $h$, it is the same as finding the tangent plane to $g$.

Comment: ohh since the z gets subtracted the answer would change and become 14(x−7)−4(y−2)−(z−45)=0?

Comment: @jainsmit Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the tangent plane is given by

$$ z=g(a,b)+g_x(a,b)(x-a)+g_y(a,b)(y-b), $$

or if prefer the other form using the gradiant

$$ \nabla (z-g(x,y))\Big|_{(7,2,45)}.((x,y,z)-(7,2,45)). $$

Comment: I'm not following you

Comment: @jainsmit: There are two ways to find the tangent plane equation. It does not matter what you use you should get the same answer.

Comment: So the answer is actually 14(x−7)−4(y−2)−(z−45)=0?

Comment: @jainsmit: Yes.

Comment: @jainsmit: Which method has you been taught?